# How to make char16_t acceptable as a template parameter to basic_ifstream?

Tags: c++, file, utf-16

I am using C++17 on macOS and `char16_t` is not acceptable as a template parameter as follow:

```
basic_ifstream<char16_t> file("c:\\file.txt", ios_base::ate);
streamsize size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
u16string str(size/2, 0);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char16_t*>(&str[0]), size);
file.close();
```

The previous code is working on windows but it doesn't work on macOS.

Also, there are indirect error `implicit instantiation of undefined template std::__1::ctype<char16_t>` appears in "istream.h", "__locale.h" and when change `char16_t` to something else that error disappear.

**Is there a solution to that problem or it's like the other poor things that in c++?**

Comment: A C++ implementation may provide a specialization for `char16_t`, but is not required to do so. If a particular C++ implementation does not provide a `char16_t` specialization, that's pretty much the end of the story.

Comment: It what way does it not work?

Comment: Can you declare the type yourself in a common header in your project?
`typedef uint16_t char16_t`

Comment: @jkb: I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error, or does it not behave properly at runtime? Add details so we understand what isn't working when you say "doesn't work".

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: I have updated my question and added something about that point.